# spring boot + SPA - redirect to index.html if prefix is not /api

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-page-application

I'm trying to fix 403 forbidden error in case the user refresh the page, and in order to do it I added a redirection to index.html for all errors:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/error)
public ModeelAndView redirect() {
   return new ModelAndView("forward:/");
}
```

The issue is.. all spring boot errors are overridden by this behavior - for example, if the user will do a POST to `/API/someApi` with the wrong parameters -he will get `error 405 (Method not allowed)` like it tried to do POTS on `index.html`.

How I can implement my redirection logic only in the UI path and keep the error handling as it was for all requests prefixed with `/API/**`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Spring way of doing things would be easier and better. For handling your errors, create a `@ControllerAdvice` class and use `@ExceptionHandler` to catch the specific errors you want to handle.